# expect lrange adding { } at beginning and end

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm observing one strange thing, when i execute below script with command line, send password is not sent. and if i execute without command line arguments it works fine. Might the issue with password having `$` at end. If `$` is present at end then puts `$pass` is printing password enclosed in `{}`.
And hence send password is wrongly sent and i'm not able to do ssh.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set name [lrange $argv 0 0]
set pass [lrange $argv 1 1]  
set server [lrange $argv 2 2] 

puts $name
puts $server
puts $pass

spawn ssh $name@$server
sleep 2
expect "assword:"
send  "$pass\r"
send  "\r"
interact
```

#### Execution

```
# ./login.sh root Abc1Cef4$ XX.XX.XX.XX
root
XX.XX.XX.XX
{Abc1Cef4$}
spawn ssh root@10.45.60.22
Password: 
Password:
```

Comment: One thing about Tcl/expect programming: you have to be aware when your data is a list and when it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lrange` would return a *list*. You should use `lindex`:

```
set name   [lindex $argv 0]
set pass   [lindex $argv 1]  
set server [lindex $argv 2]
```

Comment: Or, in one line: `lassign $argv name pass server` -- [`lassign` docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lassign.htm)

Comment: `lassign` is quite new (in Tcl 8.5). I'd rather use `foreach {a b c} {1 2 3} {}` when portability is a concern. :-)

Comment: Oh my, for certain definitions of "quite new": Tcl 8.5 was released in 2007 (https://wiki.tcl.tk/405}

Comment: There's been no supported version of Tcl without `lassign` for quite a few years now. (Very old code on 8.4 could just add in TclX, which has a functional but _very slow_ implementation and was where I stole the syntax from.)